# Add an attribute with static value with xslt

Tags: xslt

I need to add an attribute with a static value to all nodes of a specific type in an existing xml file using xslt. Basically something like this:

```
<root>
  <somenode att1="something" />
  <mynode id="1" att1="value1" att2="value2"/>
  <mynode id="2" att1="value3" att2="value4"/>
</root>
```

I need it to be like so:

```
<root>
  <somenode att1="something" />
  <mynode id="1" att1="value1" att2="value2" newatt="static string"/>
  <mynode id="2" att1="value3" att2="value4" newatt="static string"/>
</root>
```

I took a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028622/xsl-transformation-insert-attribute) but I was not able to use it for this case, if it could be used for what I'm trying.

I've never used xslt before, I really need some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="mynode">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:attribute name="newatt">static string</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(or something like that) inserted into an XSLT that does an identity transform (see http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) should do the trick for you.

Comment: +1 - The only thing I would change is: `<xsl:attribute name="newatt" select="'static string'"/>`

Comment: Thanks hcayless it did add the new attribute but also had a side effect. Now I also have an xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace. How can I prevent that from being added as well?

Comment: you could try adding the attribute exclude-result-prefixes="xsd" to your xsl:stylesheet element. Or (assuming it's boilerplate and you don't need that namespace declaration) you could just remove it from the XSLT.

Comment: @DevNull: I don't think the `select` attribute is allowed on `<xsl:attribute>`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes

Comment: @LarsH: I always forget that the `select` attribute on `xsl:attribute` is XSLT 2.0 only. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-attribute

Comment: @DevNull: thx, I didn't know it was allowed in XSLT 2.0. Was too lazy to check both specs.